# Take photo in ARKit Camera like snapchat

Tags: ios, swift, camera, arkit, sceneview

Are they any ways in swift to take high quality pictures with the sceneview camera session like snapchat does?
Or at least without the scnnode objects in the picture?

Because I don't want to init a second camera frame to take pictures. 
I want it to be integrated like snapchat camera.

Best regards,
moe

Answer (score 7):

Yep

ARSCNViews have a built in snapshot method that returns a UIImage of the ARScene

So in Objective-C you could do:

```
UIImage *image = [sceneView snapshot];
```

and in Swift

```
var image = sceneView.snapshot()
```

Comment: Thank you, but how can snapchat make a normal Camera Session to an ARKit Session ? I mean using flash light, autofocus and running ar session without interrupting the actual scene ?

Comment: I think snapchat has written their own AR Framework and have implemented it without ARKit, cause they had some AR like features previously. Can't say for sure though.